# How to handle image manipulation in IPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to be able to place images in an iPad app from a given directory and then let the user resize the image and move it around on the screen.

My question is: what's the best view to use that would allow user to resize the image (with gesture recognition) and move it around on the screen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `UIImageView` as the subview of `UIScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Quartz 2D
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-TPXREF101

Can draw anything you want.
Control with gestures

Comment: I'm not looking to draw anything. I simply want to be able to put an image on the view and let the user select it, resize it and drag it around.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `UIScrollView` with the `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` delegate method implemented.

Since you want to display an image, add a `UIImageView` to the scrollview and return it in the delegate.

Comment: what about selecting and deselecting the image with a tap? How does the visual change to know which image is selected?